# Allow only numbers with only specific alphabets in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a text box in html, i want to allow user to only input following range

0-9 and NA

there are two cases
1: user inputs range form 0-9 numbers and
2: user inputs only NA (NA denotes Not applicable)

how could i allow user to do this

I try following code but it does not work

```
<input type = "number" autocomplete="off" class = "form-control"  name="Personal_Weapons_Price" id = "Personal_Weapons_Price"   required  onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" pattern="[^0-9NA]+" />
```

Comment: is the number a single digit?

Comment: no user can input multiple digits like 23564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This Way `oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^NA0-9]/, '')"`

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^NA0-9]/, '')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the following pattern, which looks for one or more digits or `NA`.

```
^(\d+|NA)$
```

Comment: it looks, you need no regular expression signs `/` for start and end. please try again.

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad [it works for me](https://jsbin.com/negatib/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

The correct pattern is

```
pattern="^(\d+|NA)$"
```

If you also want to match `na` (so you can remove the `onkeyup` listener):

```
pattern="^(\d+|NA|na)$"
```

*Edit*: if you want to write "NA", you should change the `type` attribute type from `number` to `text`.

```html
<input 
    type="text" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    class="form-control" 
    name="Personal_Weapons_Price" 
    id="Personal_Weapons_Price" 
    required 
    pattern="^(\d+|NA|na)$" 
/>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "did not work"? What's your error? Since I tried both mine and Nina solutions, and both work.